# hide SVG icon with typeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to hide  icon in my interface and show them in other cases, here is my interface:

[icons I want to hide are inside red rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0EoZ.png)

I am working with React typeScript as a beginner. Here is my code :

```
  const hideSvgIcon = (aggregationCode: number) => {
        const listeAggregationTooltip = [2, 3, 4, 5]
        return listeAggregationTooltip.includes(aggregationCode)
    }

return (

<tr>
                                <td className="name">Critère d'agrégation</td>
                                <td className="value column-2">
                                    {aggregationDomain.map(codedValue => 
                                    <>
                                    <label id="label"  data-tooltip={getTooltipName(codedValue.name)} className={!config?.aggregationEnabled.includes(codedValue.code) ? 'text-gray' : ''}
                                        >
                                        <input type="radio" name="AggregationSelection" value={codedValue.code} checked={props.reportConfig.aggregation === codedValue.code} onChange={updateAggregation} disabled={!config?.aggregationEnabled.includes(codedValue.code)} />
                                        {codedValue.name} 
                                        </label>  
                                        {hideSvgIcon(codedValue.code) ? <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width='13' height='13'><path d="M256 512c141.4 0 256-114.6 256-256S397.4 0 256 0S0 114.6 0 256S114.6 512 256 512zM216 336h24V272H216 192V224h24 48 24v24 88h8 24v48H296 216 192V336h24zm72-144H224V128h64v64z"/></svg>
                                        :
                                        <></>}
                                    </>               
                                    )}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
)
```

I wrote a method 'hideSvgIcon' that returns true when I want to show the svg icon but it doesn't work. Any help please !

Comment: You seem to have reversed the sense of “hide” and “show”.

Comment: Can I see your array "aggregationDomain" ?

Comment: @treb my array is a state like that : `const [aggregationDomain, setAggregationDomain] = useState<{name: string, code: number}[]>([])`

Comment: @michaelLorton can you be more specific please?

Comment: When the function `hideSvgIcon` returns true, you show the icon; when it returns false, you hide it.